# How to make all elements in one line?

Tags: css, asp.net

I have this css and asp code:

```
<asp:Panel ID="dvPagingFeatureArea" Style="color: #333333; background-color: #FFCC66;" runat="server" Visible="False">
    <div style="width: 100%; margin-right: 25%;" aria-hidden="False">
        <asp:Label Text="Number:" runat="server" />
        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlFeaturePaging" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" Style="background-color: #FFCC66; width: 70px;">
        </asp:DropDownList>
    </div>
    <div>
        <asp:ImageButton ImageUrl="../Images/arrow-left-01-128.png" runat="server" ID="prevItem" Style="width: 20px;" AlternateText="previous" />
        <asp:ImageButton ImageUrl="../Images/arrow-left-01-128.png" runat="server" ID="nextItem" Style="width: 20px;" AlternateText="next" />
    </div>

</asp:Panel>
```

Here how it looks in view:

[image]

I need to change the view and to make all elements in one line.

Like this:

[image]

What do I have to change in my css code above to get desired view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wrap it inside a div with `float:left;` and set the `dropdown div` to `float: right;` and `buttons div` to `float: left;` - here is [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fb78wkpz/) (*I have removed asp controls*):

```
<div style="float:left">
  <div style="float:right" aria-hidden="False">
    <label>Number:</label>
    <select ID="ddlFeaturePaging" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" Style="background-color: #FFCC66; width: 70px;">
    </select>
  </div>
  <div style="float: left;">
    <input type="button" Style="width: 120px;" value="button" />
    <input type="button" Style="width: 120px;" value="button" />
  </div>
</div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

basically, have the first `div` float right:

```
<div style="width: 100%; margin-right: 25%; float: right;" aria-hidden="False">
```

Comment: I tryed but arrows in lower row